# Map SharePoint Online Library as Network Drive With PowerShell in a Scheduler Job

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to map a SharePoint online document library to a network drive with PowerShell. It worked when I execute PowerShell with my account but failing when I try to execute same cod in a scheduler job whcih is configured to run as my account

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\test.log";

$SPLibraryURL ="\\mycompany.sharepoint.com\DavWWWRoot\sites\Sandpit\TEST Incoming Mail"

Write-Host $SPLibraryURL

New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $SPLibraryURL

$sourceRiskFile = Get-ChildItem "B:"

Foreach ($file in $sourceRiskFile)
{

 Write-Host $file.Name

}

Stop-Transcript
```

I have also tried this URL but no success

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandpit/TEST%20Incoming%20Mail
```

Error I am getting is

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root
"https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandpit/TEST%20Incoming%20Mail" either does not exist,
or it is not a folder.

job configuration is

[image]

There must be something to do with Scheduler job as same code works fine if I run PowerShell directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will ever be able to do this. Several reasons:

- Even when doing this manually, your mapping will stop working from time to time. For example when you log out.
- You need to open the site you map using Internet Explorer
- Your scheduled script won't be able to open the Internet Explorer with the UI. Especially when you "run as" in your script.
- Many tried to do what you are doing and failed. You could do this with SP on-prem though, but it won't work with SPO.

If you want users to use a mapped folder, then it's a bad idea. WebDav protocol has many issues: it's very slow, it does not support collaboration for Office documents, it has issues with SharePoint columns, etc. Instead, I recommend using the OneDrive sync tool. Although, you will have to ask users to sync the library manually.

**Alternative**

In your scheduled job, you want to run a PowerShell script that connects to SharePoint Online and downloads a file. You can use [PowerShell Pnp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) for this purpose.

Comment: I am currently doing it with PNP but I have to either sore credentials in the script or in Windows Password Manager where anyone can go and edit, is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use Edge Browser and Selenium to automate mapping your Sharepoint drive

[Selenium Powershell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell)